# SendGrid email using MailHelper

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid mailhelper (as part of C# SDK) to send email. I need to send to multiple users, and hence I am using Personalization.

I get an error : Bad Request

This is my code:

```
 static async Task Execute(string sub, string body, List<Recipient> recipients)
    {
        string apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGrid_ApiKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

        dynamic sg = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);

        SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email from = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email("test1@gmail.com");
        string subject = sub;
        Personalization personalization = new Personalization();

       SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email emails = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email();
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var recp in recipients)
        {
            emails.Address = recp.Email;
            emails.Name = recp.FirstName + " " + recp.LastName;
            personalization.AddTo(emails);
            i++;
        }
        SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email to = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email("test1@gmail.com");

        Content content = new Content("text/plain", body);
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
        mail.AddPersonalization(personalization);
        dynamic response = await sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
    }
```

I appreciate if someone could advise me what am I doing incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendgrid API responds with bad request when there are more than 1 email address that is the same in the Personalization object. Make sure all the emails are unique

Comment: Thanks @KyleT12. This was the case with mine.